# How to combine property arrays of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**How to zip any number of arrays, which are properties of an object, in a specific format in javascript to get the following outcome?**

This is the original object.

```
const items = {
distance: [1,5,12, ...],
time: [10,20,30,..],
...
}
```

expected outcome :

```
const result = [
{distance: 1, time: 10},
{distance: 5, time: 20},
{distance: 12, time: 30},
...
]
```

I tried with loadash zip and vanilla js mapping and all. It is not working!

This is a sample of what I have tried:

But not working!

```
zip(
  Object.entries(items ).map(
    ([key, values]) =>
      values.map((val, index) => ({
        [key]: val[index],
      }))
  )
))
```

Answer (score 1):

With plain Javascript, you could reduce the entries and map objects.

```js
const items = { distance: [1, 5, 12], time: [10, 20, 30] },
result = Object
    .entries(items)
    .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => ({ ...r[i], [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy with lodsah [`_.zipWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipWith):

```js
const items = {
    distance: [1,5,12],
    time: [10,20,30]
}


const result = _.zipWith(
      items.distance, 
      items.time, 
      (distance,time) => ({distance,time})
);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla JavaScript, you can use `Object.fromEntries`, `Object.entries`, `map`,... to create the result array:

```js
const zipObject = obj => Object.values(obj)[0].map((_, i) =>
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => [key, val[i]])
    )
);

// Demo
const items = {
  distance: [1,5,12],
  time: [10,20,30],
};

console.log(zipObject(items));
```